# Django REST Swagger how to process response POST api (function based)

Tags: python, django, rest, swagger, imagefield

I am trying to accept a image file that has been post using my Django REST function based POST API. This is based on https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs

I am getting this error screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUA5.jpg)

```
Object of type 'TypeError' is not JSON serializable
```

for doing this

```
face_image = request.data.get('face_image')
```

and whats the right step to save it to the model, would it be something like this

```
employee.face_image = face_image
```

Here is how I define the API

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def update_employee_image(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: This API deletes/uninstalls a device.
    parameters:
      - name: employee_id
        type: integer
        required: true
        location: form
      - name: face_image
        type: file
        required: true
        location: form
    """
    employee_id = request.POST.get('employee_id')
    face_image = request.data.get('face_image') <--- this causes the error
```

Here is the model with the imagefield

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ....
    face_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='face_image/', blank=True)
```

Can someone let me know the right way to do this ? process the image from the post and save it to the model. My full source code is in the those links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileUploadParser solves this issue and able to accept the image post

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
face_image_obj = request.data['face_image']
```